# For git log, the difference between options of --follow and --find-renames

Tags: git, git-log

Suppose I only need to work on a single file. From the git-log man page, it seems like I should use --follow. What confuses me is that for --find-renames, I can specify the threshold on the similarity index, while there is no such threshold for --follow.

My question is why I do not need to specify a threshold for --follow to find renaming?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify a threshold with `--find-renames`, it will be applied when using `--follow`. But when you only specify `--follow` the default similarity index is used (which should be alright in most cases).

Follow requires rename detection to work, but rename detection itself is also useful for e.g. `git show`, `git status`, etc. I recommend enabling it by default using:

```
git config --global diff.renames true
```